# Cross account SNS SQS subscription set up (CDK)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

I'm trying to set up a cross account subscription between a SQS queue (in account 11111111111) and a SNS topic (in account 22222222222). However, I've been having trouble having this done thru CDK. Any help would be appreciated.

The following is the CDK code to set up the subscription in SQS queue (the SQS queue setup is standard and omitted here),

```
// SNS topic in another account
const snsTopic = sns.Topic.fromTopicArn(
    this,
    'id',
    'arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:22222222222:id',
);

snsTopic.addSubscription(new SqsSubscription(sqsQueue));
```

Then I followed this [AWS article](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-send-message-to-sqs-cross-account.html) to give SNS topic access policy to be subscribed by account 11111111111. The following is the topic's access policy,

```
{
  "Version": "2008-10-17",
  "Id": "__default_policy_ID",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "__default_statement_ID",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "*"
      },
      "Action": [
        "SNS:Publish",
        "SNS:RemovePermission",
        "SNS:SetTopicAttributes",
        "SNS:DeleteTopic",
        "SNS:ListSubscriptionsByTopic",
        "SNS:GetTopicAttributes",
        "SNS:AddPermission",
        "SNS:Subscribe"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:22222222222:id",
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "AWS:SourceOwner": "22222222222"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "*"
      },
      "Action": "sns:Subscribe",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:22222222222:id",
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "AWS:SourceOwner": "11111111111"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

As you can see here, this policy gives full access to the account owner (22222222222) and subscribe rights to another account (11111111111).

However, when I deploy my CDK changes, the cloudformation keeps throwing the following error indicating account 11111111111 doesn't have authorization to subscribe to the topic in 22222222222.

```
User: arn:aws:sts::11111111111:assumed-role/PipelinesChangeSetExec-19a3877f4882528dec93b2760e3771af2ccd62c
6/AWSCloudFormation is not authorized to perform: SNS:Subscribe on resource: arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:2222222
2222:id because no resource-based policy allows the SNS:Subscribe action (Service: AmazonSNS; Status Code:
 403; Error Code: AuthorizationError; Request ID: 45ea9a58-13ce-50b9-8b07-c16de46f3a53; Proxy: null)
```

I think I'm following the setup guide from AWS. Can anyone point out where I might be wrong? Thanks

Comment: This is the permission given to the sts role, I believe it should have all access? I think this is the PipelinesChangeSet role bc this is the only role specified in the CDK.


{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": "*",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Effect": "Allow"
        }
    ]
}